# PowerShell download exe from public Github

Tags: powershell

I'm unable to download a .exe file from Github. Script works for different sites and downloads files without issues.

https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/tag/v13.1.0

This is the .exe I'm trying to download:
https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/download/v13.1.0/ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe

```
>$DownloadUrl = "https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/download/v13.1.0/ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe"
>$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$DownloadUrl" -Method Head
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:2 char:16
+ $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$DownloadUrl" -Method Head
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Full script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3"
$DownloadUrl = "https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/download/v13.1.0/ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe"
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$DownloadUrl" -Method Head
Write-Output "Downloading $DownloadUrl"
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $WebResponse.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("%20", " ") -Destination "C:\Users\Pegavo\Desktop\PS\"
```

Comment: Remove the quotes: `"$DownloadUrl"` should be `$DownloadUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply use `Invoke-WebRequest` with `-OutFile` parameter.

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/download/v13.1.0/ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe -OutFile "ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe"
```

This command will download the file from GitHub and store the result to a file in your current directory.

Or, you can use `WebClient`.

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.DownloadFile("https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/download/v13.1.0/ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe", "E:\your\path\ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe")
```

I tested both on my local machine. Both worked.

Moreover, if you want to understand why Start-BitsTransfer won't work, [here.](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/bits-transfer-with-github/)

---

#### Edit:

You can get the filename automatically like this one, using `Split-Path`:

```
$url = "https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/download/v13.1.0/ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe"
$file= Split-Path $url -Leaf #file is ShareX-13.1.0-setup.exe now
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $file
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to get the filename and output it without manually writing it in the script? Like it's for `$WebResponse.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("%20", " ")` or only way is to use split/regex to get the correct filename to destination?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can use `Split-Path` to get the filename with extension. See again if it works in your case now. Please remember to mark my answer as accepted if it does! :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using HEAD? GET seems to work

Comment: GET doesn't work, I tried. `Start-BitsTransfer : An incorrect value is specified in the Source parameter or in the Destination parameter. Verify that the directory and file names in the Source and 
Destination parameters are correct.
At line:1 char:1` Also when I manually name the file I download `"C:\Users\Pegavo\Desktop\PS\sharex.exe"` I get this error: `Start-BitsTransfer : HTTP status 403: The client does not have sufficient access rights to the requested server object.`